# How to retrieve values from drop down when select tag style attribute is set as display: none; in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, display

I am trying to scrap all combination of categories of drop down from one site. However text attribute of option is coming as blank only. Although while inspecting, I can see text is present for each option.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.fiyo.nl/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select_device_chosen"]/a').click()
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-device"]'))
print ([o.text for o in select.options])
```

**Output:**

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

if I get text, I want to loop through all values to get different combination of other drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<select>` tag is having *style* attribute set as **display: none;** so you can use the following code block to print the options :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select_device_chosen"]/a').click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='select-device']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='select-device']"))
print ([o.text for o in select.options])
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do you know what should I learn to figure out this kind of problem by myself?

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara The best way to figure out these problems is to face it and solve it for yourself and also for other stackoverflow community members facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you try like the following, the style tag is not a barrier to consider.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.fiyo.nl/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select_device_chosen"]/a').click()
items = ' '.join([item.get_attribute("textContent") for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='chosen-results']//*[@class='active-result']")])
print(items.split())

driver.quit()
```